# Prevent Duplicate Trigger

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-trigger, salesforce-development

while creating account , check if there is an account available with the same name and phone number. if there is duplicates throw error while listing the id : sample error message : “duplicate found 50130000000014c,50130000000015c “.

I want to throw an error while listing the Id but the code is not working.

Comment: Any special reason to not use built-in duplicate rules? Post the code you have so far. And... really account object? What's 501 prefix for? Solution?